# How should I manage DbContext Lifetime in MVC Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core, entity-framework-core

From the [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection)

> Entity Framework contexts **should** be added to the services container
>   using the `Scoped` lifetime. This is taken care of automatically if you
>   use the helper methods as shown above. Repositories that will make use
>   of Entity Framework should use the same lifetime.

I always thought, that I should create a new `Context` for every single unit of work I have to process. This let me think, if I have a `ServiceA` and `ServiceB`, which are applying different actions on the `DbContext` that they should get a different Instance of `DbContext`.

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection) reads as following:

> - `Transient` objects are always different; a new instance is provided to every controller and every service.
> - `Scoped` objects are the same within a request, but different across different request

Going back to `ServiceA` and `ServiceB`, it sounds to me, `Transient` is more suitable.

I have researched, that the Context should only saved once per `HttpRequest`, but I really do not understand how this does work.

Especially if we take a look at one Service:

```
using (var transaction = dbContext.Database.BeginTransaction())
{
    //Create some entity
    var someEntity = new SomeEntity();
    dbContext.SomeEntity.Add(someEntity);

    //Save in order to get the the id of the entity
    dbContext.SaveChanges();

    //Create related entity
    var relatedEntity = new RelatedEntity
    {
        SomeEntityId = someEntity.Id
    };
    dbContext.RelatedEntity.Add(relatedEntity)
    dbContext.SaveChanges();
    transaction.Commit();
}
```

Here we need to Save the context in order to get the ID of an Entity which is related to another one we just have created.

At the same time another service could update the same context. From what I have read, `DbContext` is not thread safe.

Should I use `Transient` in this case? Why does the documentation suggest, I **should** use `Scoped`?

Do I miss some important part of the framework?

Comment: Never use transient `DbContext` registration. Transient lifetime will create a new instance of the service **each** time it is request by another service. This will lead to multiple `DbContext`s per request. There is no issue in reusing the same `DbContext` instance inside the same request: each request is bound to a single thread, so there is no thread safety issue at all.

Comment: But what happens if the services are processed in parallel for what ever reason (Task.Start for example)? @FedericoDipuma

Comment: What do you mean with *in parallel*? Are you explicitly spawning a new thread into which you use the same `DbContext`?

Comment: Yes, for example if I explicit start a new thread, and want do inject the DbContext. I assume it is the same DbContext instance resolved if configured `Scoped`? @FedericoDipuma

Comment: `Task.Start` without any `await`/`.Wait()`? That's an issue no matter what scope you register your `DbContext` instance. You should never do *fire-and-forget* or similar tasks inside a Request lifecycle (because there may be no Request at all during the task execution). There are libraries specifically for that (Hangfire, Fluentscheduler, etc.). Those libraries handle lifetime for their dependencies appropriately.

Comment: I just want it to be possible to process multiple services at once, but ofcourse synchronize them after that. For example: `Task.WhenAll(serviceA.DoSomethingWithContext, ServiceB.DoSomethingElseWithContext)` @FedericoDipuma

Comment: I do not understand what is the benefit in executing I/O bound operations in parallel (like db access), but if you really want to continue to that path the only option I think you have is to inject some form of factory method for your `DbContext` (something like `services.AddSingleton<Func<DbContext>>(s => new Func<DbContext>(() => new MyDbContext(/*..*/)));`), and manage the lifetime of them yourself with `using` statements.

Comment: The problem is my service is mixed cpu/io bound. But I think thats an xy problem right now. Thank you :)

Comment: If you have a background *worker* thread, then that thread shouldn’t use *any* dependency from your request-bound dependency scope since it’s likely living longer than the request. It should open its own scope to prevent lifetime issues (e.g. when the request is over, the dependency scope is being closed, which will likely dispose lots of objects—you don’t want to hold a reference to those then).

Answer (score 35, accepted):

As others already explained, you *should* use a scoped dependency for database contexts to make sure it will be properly reused. For concurrency, remember that you can query the database asynchronously too, so you might not need actual threads.

If you do *need* threads, i.e. background workers, then it’s likely that those will have a different lifetime than the request. As such, those threads should *not* use dependencies retrieved from the request scope. When the request ends and its dependency scope is being closed, disposable dependencies will be properly disposed. For other threads, this would mean that their dependencies might end up getting disposed although they still need them: Bad idea.

Instead, you should explicitly open a new dependency scope for every thread you create. You can do that by injecting the [`IServiceScopeFactory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.iservicescopefactory) and creating a scope using [`CreateScope`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.iservicescopefactory#Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_IServiceScopeFactory_CreateScope). The resulting object will then contain a service provider which you can retrieve your dependencies from. Since this is a seperate scope, scoped dependencies like database contexts will be recreated for the lifetime of this scope.

In order to avoid getting into the service locator pattern, you should consider having one central service your thread executes that brings together all the necessary dependencies. The thread could then do this:

```
using (var scope = _scopeFactory.CreateScope())
{
    var service = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<BackgroundThreadService>();
    service.Run();
}
```

The `BackgroundThreadService` and all its dependency can then follow the common dependency injection way of receiving dependencies.

Comment: Very nice :) Thank you for the detailed explaination.

Comment: re “you can query the database asynchronously too, so you might not need actual threads”. Even in this case, you need a distinct `DbContext` instance for each concurrent query. Otherwise, you will get [an errror about how concurrent operations are unsupported](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/blob/04607ac00983705b3b1d4d4ca9834364edd36a01/src/EFCore/Internal/ConcurrencyDetector.cs#L37). See the warning at https://learn.microsoft.com/ef/core/querying/async

Comment: This solution will also work to create a fire and forget endpoint - ty        _ = Task.Run(async () =>
                {
                    using (var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope())
                    {

Answer (score 2):

I believe you wouldn't faced with concurrency issues in most cases when you use scoped lifetime. Even in example you posted there is no concurrency problems as services in current request will be called subsequently. I cant even imagine case when you will run 2 or more services in parallel (its possible but not usual) in context of one HTTP request(scope).

Lifetimes its just a way to store your data(to be simple here). Just look on some lifetime managers in popular DI frameworks, all of them works pretty match the same - this is just dictionary like objects that implementing disposable pattern. Using Transient I believe your get object method will always return null so DI will create new instance each time it requested. SingleInstance will store objects in something like static concurrent dictionary so container will create instance only once and then receive existing one.

Scoped is usually mean **scope object** is used to store created objects. In asp net pipeline it usually mean the same as per request (as scope can be passed through the pipeline)

To be short - don't worry just use scoped it is safe and you can call this as per request.

I've tried to be very simple in my explanation, you can always look to the source code to find as match details as you need here https://github.com/aspnet/DependencyInjection