# What is the correct lifetime for the dependency injection of DatastoreDb and DatastoreClient classes

Tags: c#, google-cloud-datastore

I am currently investigating the use of Google Datastore in conjunction with .Net Core 2 webapi applications.

I am trying to work out the correct lifetime for injecting DatastoreDb instances and/or DatastoreClient instances into Repository components.
I am guessing the lifetime should be either scoped (one per http api request) or transient (one for every internal implementation call).

Looking at the implementation code, DatastoreDb is a light weight wrapper component whereas DataStoreClient has slightly more construction overhead as it constructs the underlying rest API proxies.

There are also two settings classes, CallSettings and DatastoreSettings which I guess could have a static lifetime via use of some form of wrapper class.

I cannot find much help in the documentation or samples on how to manage the lifetime of these classes and what the correct approach should be.

Any advise would be gratefully received.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How should I manage DbContext Lifetime in MVC Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46412734)

Answer (score 1):

If the two settings classes are guaranteed to be static during the application's lifetime then you are safe in making them singletons and that is the approach I would take.

The scope for the datastore and the client will depend more on how your application uses them then on the objects themselves.

In general, a transient approach is the safest since you will get a new object for every use and you won't need to be concerned with any potential concurrency issues. I would recommend going this route unless you find you are having performance issues due to the extra instantiations that you are unable resolve via other means.

A request scope may also be appropriate, especially if your application needs to make many instances of these objects per request. In general, this will also be a thread-safe approach unless you have requests that spin off multiple threads or that call into these objects asynchronously. If that is the case, you will need to ensure you handle concurrency across any shared instances.