# EF Core context not disposing of change tracking entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Using EF Core 2.1 to insert 135k records.  Once the request is finished, I would expect the context to be disposed of and along with it, the `ChangeTracking` entities to be cleared, however, it's holding on to all 135k records and using a lot of memory in the process.

We are using ASP.NET Core 2.1 and injecting the EF Context from the DI container.  Since the DI container should dispose of the scoped context at the end of the request, it should not be holding on to these values.  Even calling dispose manually at the end of the controller does not seem to affect the change tracking entities.

Below is the output of the heap view of the memory usage after the request has finished.   Diving into the path, I'm seeing a lot of EF Core classes and strangely seeing a `EntityQueryable` instance for a different entity (`System` vs `InvoicePendingItem`).

[image: Heap]

---

The context is being registered in `Startup.cs`:

```
services.AddDbContext<EFContext>(options => options.UseMySql(
  GetDBConnectionString()
));
```

Comment: What service lifetime is the DBContext registered with?

Comment: Can you show the code that is registering the DBContext with the container?

Comment: @GaryStewart, added it.  We're using the default method, which should be a scoped lifetime.

Comment: How are you verifying that there are "135k records" being tracked after the DbContext is disposed and the request finishes? Is it only by checking the managed memory heap?

Comment: The reason I ask is that objects on the heap stay there until they are garbage collected. Garbage collection is non deterministic meaning it occurs when the .net framework determines it needs to be executed. Objects on the heap might also not be released when garbage collection occurs depending on what generation they are. So these 135,000 instances could stay on the heap even though the request has completed and the DbContext instance has been disposed. What you should *not* see is references to these 135,000 instances via a new `DbContext` instance on a different or new request.

Comment: 1. Was the heap snapshot made after the request was finished AND a garbage collection has been performed? (e.g. dotMemory can trigger GC).
2. Are there some services registered as singleton who also use a DbContext (so that it would be turned into a singleton as well)

Comment: @Igor, we we're going by the number of records on the heap.  Garbage collection does not seem to affect it as I ran context.Dispose() and GC.Collect() manually.  You may be right though, doing a second request drives my memory usage to almost double (1.7GB) but still only shows 135k records.  It is strange since my heap size is 100MB but my memory usage is 1.7GB.

Comment: @Devon is the call to save SaveChanges or SaveChangesAsync ?

Comment: @GaryStewart await SaveChangesAsync

Comment: `GC.Collect` won't do anything until after there are no more references (so calling it in the same request has no affect because there are still references in the DI framework for that request) and even then objects could survive if they were promoted in generation or have a pending finalizer.

Comment: @Devon, I have found that using EF to save that number of objects takes a considerable amount of time and switched to EFCore.BulkExtensions nuget package which did the same work in seconds.  I wonder if your request is actually timing out yet the DB Context save is still running to completion after the request has ended?

Comment: One thing that bit us was having a singleton service that made use of our DbContext (ie. injected the context into the constructor). This had the unfortunate side-effect of also making the DbContext a singleton, even though it was declared as scoped in the DI container. Not saying that's what is happening here, but it might be something to check.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a question about:
[How should I manage DbContext Lifetime in MVC Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46412734/how-should-i-manage-dbcontext-lifetime-in-mvc-core)

As for change tracking, it is enabled by default and is removed when you dispose of the context. However you can also disable change tracking by setting the AutoDetectChangesEnabled property of DbContext to false

```
context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
```

Additionally, when you insert +100k items you should do that in batches of for example 2k for performance and memory reasons.

Comment: Where did you find the Configuration of the DbContext?
As far as I found out -so far- your should use Change Tracking: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext) 
See also: [link](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/master/src/EFCore/ChangeTracking/ChangeTracker.cs)

Comment: Specific documentation : [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.changetracking.changetracker.autodetectchangesenabled?view=efcore-3.1)

Answer (score -3):

You can implement the IDispose interface in your classes correctly and manage how the class will be destroyed when it is no longer used, implement the interface and use the Dispose Pattern.

[image]

Read about in this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose

Comment: Try override dispose of dbcontext, then implement correct Dispose pattern.
public void Dispose()
{
   // Dispose of unmanaged resources.
   Dispose(true);
   // Suppress finalization.
   GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
}